# Minkowski Difference calculation in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, detection, game-physics

I am experimenting with a custom Physics engine written in javascript. I know that i can find a lot of already written engines like cannon or physis, but i think i really need to understand 3d math, vectors and quaternions to have the skills to write a real decent webgame.

I have the gravity and collision detection (first with AABB then raycaster) functioning, but i have a lot of problems with object overlap (things fall inside other things).

So i am going crazy to write in javascript on three.js the Minkowski Difference calculation to get the Minimum Translational Distance and if the resultant shape contains or not the origin.

I have studied a lot various docs like this one: http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/20/collision-detection-for-dummies/

with few results. Help will be appreciated.